# Context updating without being set in React.js

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I am trying to set a value to the value of context/state but it is updating the contaxt/state value instead. As you can see below, I am setting newParticipants equal to the array of global.participants, then when I click the button, it takes the value of that button and pushes it to the newParticipants array. For some reason it is updating global.paricipants as if I were calling setGlobal. What am I missing? I am not trying to update the context.

```
const { global, setGlobal } = useContext(GlobalContext);

let newParticipants = global.participants;
const click = (event) => {
    newParticipants.push(event.currentTarget.attributes[1].value);
    axios.put(
        "http://localhost:8080/update/participants",
        { old: global.participants, new: newParticipants },
        {
        headers: { authorization: "Bearer: " + localStorage.getItem("Auth") },
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the original array as you are referencing the same array after assigning it to `newParticipants`, you should instead clone the participant list before updating it

```
const { global, setGlobal } = useContext(GlobalContext);

// shallow clone the list
let newParticipants = [...global.participants];
const click = (event) => {
    newParticipants.push(event.currentTarget.attributes[1].value);
    ... 
};
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I was treating my Array as if it were a variable! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to have helped.